# How to know a StreamGeometry is a Line

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a collection of StreamGeometrys. Each StreamGeometry could be any shape. I just want to pick up the StreamGeometrys that are lines. How can I know a StreamGeometry is a line.

**Background:**
I get collection of StreamGeometrys from an interface. The interface is given by other team and doesn't return the information that what the Geometry is. (I may discuss with them to make an update, but it involve the architecture change.) I have a function to group the Geometrys and get the outline of the group. Originally, I add them to a GeometryGroup, then I use  Geometry.GetOutlinedPathGeometry to get the outline of the GeometryGroup. The behavior is good.

**Problem**:But when the Geometrys number increases to more than 200, GetOutlinedPathGeometry becomes extremely slow.

**Current solution**:Then I have to make a compromise to get an outline not that accurate. Instead of GetOutlinedPathGeometry, I use Geometry.Combine to combine the Geometrys. Geometry.Combine is mainly used for closed Geometry. When a Geometry is not closed, it will find the nearest points to make it closed. This behavior somehow reduce the complexity of the overall outline that GetOutlinedPathGeometry can get a result quicker.

**How I get to this question**:But one problem is that Geometry.Combine will omit Line Shapes. After combine all Geometrys, Lines are not in the group. So I want to find those lines and use GetOutlinedPathGeometry to get their outlines first. Then use their outlines to combine with others.

**Also**, even I have the Geometry type information, it could not help too much. Because Geometry.Combine will omit any Line Shapes that can be made of any Geometry type. Line, Path even Rectangle can all make a Line shape.

**Other attempts**:I tried to use GetOutlinedPathGeometry to get outline for each geometry first, then to combine. The performance improves a little bit but still very slow.

Comment: Too little context. Where do your `StreamGeometry` objects come from? Why don't you already know which are lines? Why is it important that you know which are lines? You seem to have the [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)...what are you actually trying to do, and how did you get yourself into a situation where you need information the object doesn't normally provide? Edit your question so that it includes a good [mcve] showing the context and explain _specifically_ what you've tried and why that didn't work.

Comment: I'm really pressed hard to find any questions that @PeterDuniho didn't raise, except maybe what's your favorite color ...

Comment: My favorite color is transparent. Can you help me out now?

Comment: Ah .... transparent ... the color of deep knowledge ... i approve. Also, your question is now light years better than the original. well done. dose the current answer help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just drop this code in and you can use `StreamGeometry.IsLine()` to check for lines.

```
public static class StreamGeometryExtensions
{
    public static bool IsLine(this StreamGeometry sg, double sampleRate = 0.2, decimal tolerance = 0
    {
        PathGeometry g = sg.GetFlattenedPathGeometry();
        if (g.MayHaveCurves())
        {
            return false;
        }

        Point origin, originTangent;
        Point end, endTangent;
        g.GetPointAtFractionLength(0, out origin, out originTangent);
        g.GetPointAtFractionLength(1, out end, out endTangent);

        Vector originToEnd = end - origin;

        for (double i = 0; i < 1; i += sampleRate)
        {
            Point current, currentTangent;
            g.GetPointAtFractionLength(i, out current, out currentTangent);

            Vector currentToEnd = end - current;
            Vector originTocurrent = current - origin;

            decimal l1 = (decimal)(originTocurrent.Length + currentToEnd.Length);
            decimal l2 = (decimal)originToEnd.Length;

            if (Math.Abs(l2 - l1) > (l2 * tolerance))
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

The code "samples" the path every X% (example 0.2 = 20%) and checks if the origin, the end and the current sample point are on a line.

The code is a very general solution to the problem and can definetly be optimized for specific scenarios where performance is important.

I measured the performance for following Paths: (sampleRate = 0.2, tolerance = 0)

```
    <Path Data="M 217,172 L 10 50, 50 30, 70 40, 100 300 10 50, 50 30, 70 40, 100 300,  10 50, 50 30, 70 40, 100 300 10 50, 50 30, 70 40, 100 300,  10 50, 50 30, 70 40, 100 300 10 50, 50 30, 70 40, 100 300,  10 50, 50 30, 70 40, 100 300 10 50, 50 30, 70 40, 100 300"></Path>
    <Path Data="M 217,172 L 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20"></Path>
    <Path Data="M 217,172 L 10 50, 50 30, 70 40, 100 300 10 50, 50 30, 70 40, 100 300,  10 50, 50 30, 70 40, 100 300 10 50, 50 30, 70 40, 100 300,  10 50, 50 30, 70 40, 100 300 10 50, 50 30, 70 40, 100 300,  10 50, 50 30, 70 40, 100 300 10 50, 50 30, 70 40, 100 300"></Path>
    <Path Data="M 217,172 L 10 50, 50 30, 70 40, 100 300 10 50, 50 30, 70 40, 100 300,  10 50, 50 30, 70 40, 100 300 10 50, 50 30, 70 40, 100 300,  10 50, 50 30, 70 40, 100 300 10 50, 50 30, 70 40, 100 300,  10 50, 50 30, 70 40, 100 300 10 50, 50 30, 70 40, 100 300"></Path>
    <Path Data="M 217,172 L 10 50, 50 30, 70 40, 100 300 10 50, 50 30, 70 40, 100 300,  10 50, 50 30, 70 40, 100 300 10 50, 50 30, 70 40, 100 300,  10 50, 50 30, 70 40, 100 300 10 50, 50 30, 70 40, 100 300,  10 50, 50 30, 70 40, 100 300 10 50, 50 30, 70 40, 100 300"></Path>
    <Path Data="M 217,172 L 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20, 20 20"></Path>
```

On an i7 4790 i got these times:

```
80µs - False
390µs - True
86µs - False
82µs - False
69µs - False
355µs - True
```

Comment: Thanks. It seems the only way to check StreamGeometry is a Line.